# Javascript Executed Source With cURL

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

I'm trying to get the html source of web page. Howewer, some of the html elements that I need are executed with javascript, when I try to get the source with cURL, there is nothing to get any of these executed codes. When I login the page and inspect element, there is no problem but I couldn't handle it with cURL. I need some suggestions and help. The web page is  [here](http://netspor11.tv)

And I should get all the index.php?id=xxxx adresses which are located in left menu. Thank you.

UPDATED: cURL can not execute the javascript coding, however [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/)

can be used for this situation.

Comment: That's not so easy, because cURL is a library to made HTTP requests. But you need a HTML rendering engine like Blink, Gecko, EdgeHTML or WebKit to parse the HTML and execute the JS code.

Comment: @Kyoya Do you have and idea for the solution. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry I never tried to use a HTML rendering engine together with PHP. You can try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

Comment: That's why I like to help others. It's the moment when I read such "thank you"s :D